# Defining dialects for a DSL using ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4, dsl, rule-engine

I am building a simple DSL to validate FIX messages using ANTLRv4.
My grammar currently supports dialect 1 below (mostly comparison operators), and I am looking to additionally support dialect 2.

Is it possible to define grammars for dialects that inherit and/or extend from the parent grammar?

For instance, other developers using my grammar should be able to define their own dialects and express rules that obey that dialect, without having to write the entire DSL from scratch.

Rules in dialect 1:

`tag 9 > 0
tag 59 = "A"`

Same rules in dialect 2:

`tag 9 must be greater than 0
tag 59 must be equal to "A"`

Comment: You must have really smart users if you expect them to modify the base grammar.  What is the application that has such smart users?

Comment: To clarify, the users are expected to use the DSL, but other developers should be able to define their own dialects. Apologies, I should have clarified earlier, edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Antlr4 includes a mechanism called `import`s to let you break up a grammar into logical and reusable chunks.   When you import one grammar into another it behaves sort of like object-oriented inheritance, which could be useful in maintaining a number of dialects of a DSL.

See [this page](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md) for the basics.   Details in the [Definitive Antlr4 Reference](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) book.

Comment: that looks interesting, will try this out and update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can define grammar dialects with ANTLR's direct help.

Of course, in order to consider making any changes to your grammar, they must have a strong understanding of what is in the current grammar specification.   So you must be allowing them to *view* the current grammar in some kind of window, before they make a change.

You could just let them view it in an editor window, and edit it directly.

Comment: The existing grammar is editable. I am exploring if there is any way of extending the existing grammar, such that other developers using the existing grammar are not affected. I am referring to extension rather than modification here.

Comment: If you want "other users" to not be affected, you'll need to store a derived copy per user.  That's independent of how its gets derived.